# Possible design pattern suggestions?

Tags: vb.net, performance, algorithm

I was wondering if anyone can suggest a suitable design pattern for achieving the following:

I have a payslip, each slip shows my previous pay and my current pay. Each payslip should not need to duplicate fields, but rather point the `current` value to the `previous` value in the next slip.

On top of all this, I also need to be able to retrieve any given payslip at any point in time (preferably O(1)).

Here's a visual to help understand my problem.

```
[key:"1"]     [key:"2"]     [key:"3"]
+------+      +------+      +------+
|      |      |      |      |      |
| Curr | <--- | Prev |      | Curr |
| Null |      | Curr | <--- | Prev |
|      |      |      |      |      |
+------+      +------+      +------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `Each payslip should not need to duplicate fields` what fields? What data is held in there? Can you duplicate the salary of month1 if it is identical to month2?

Comment: Yes sorry, I should clarify, what I mean is that I should not need to retrieve the previous value from the DB again once it has already been done on the payslip prior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**:  *I am not a VB programmer*, and the syntax below may not apply.  Assuming VB has a `Map` interface, you could use that for your lookups `O(1)`

```
Map<Integer, CompositeValue> = some hash based map
```

and declare a class (assuming VB lets you create classes) `CompositeValue` as such:

```
class CompositeValue { 
    Integer previousKey;
    Value value;
}
```

Now, once you've retrieved a `CompositeValue` from the `Map`, you have the means to get it's real value (`value`), and to retrieve the previous value using `previousKey`.

Just a thought.

Comment: How would i access the map internally within the class?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  You could make the Map static, or simply pass it into the constructor - but really, you shouldn't need to do that

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't wrap my head around the implementation at the time, with your input I managed to implement this successfully. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Give your `PaySlip` class a `PreviousPaySlipKey` property, which will be null for the very first pay slip. In your database, this should be a foreign key to the `PaySlip`'s `Key` property.

This way, if you have a `PaySlip`, you can find the key of the previous pay slip, and query the database for the payslip with that key.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking DBs here, every payslip should be given a sequential ID (also called auto-increment in some RDBMS). This will be the primary key (so it's automatically indexed). Assuming you retrieved the payslip you wanted, here is how to get previous one from DB:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PaySlip WHERE PaySlipID < @PaySlipID ORDER BY PaySlipID Desc
```

And the next one:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PaySlip WHERE PaySlipID > @PaySlipID ORDER BY PaySlipID
```

You will probably have payslips for multiple employees stored in a single table, so just add to the WHERE condition.

It is counter productive to store references to previous/next payslip on each payslip.